# How to convert String to an object type

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using emberjs to find stuff but the question is more JS related than Ember.

I have two variables: `var type = "stars"; var term = "5"`

I have a property called stars in my API.

When I do: `App.Response.find({stars: term});` I find results

However, when I do: `App.Response.find({type: term});` I **don't** find results. I want this to be translated to `App.Response.find({stars: term})` since `type` has value `"stars"`

I am assuming this is because `type` (with value `stars`) is not being understood as a hash key?

Comment: Correct. That's essentially `App.Response.find({type: 5})`.

Comment: hmm how can I fix it such that `App.Response.find({type: term})` is same as `App.Response.find({stars: term})` since type = "stars"

Comment: @Anthony See my answer below, I believe it should solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly - it will not evaluate object keys. If you want to dynamically create that object as `{stars:5}` you could do:

```
var obj = {};
obj[type] = term;//Using the array notation will cause JS to evaluate type to "stars" and use that as the key
//obj is now {stars:5}
App.Response.find(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no dynamic way to set object keys in an object literal.

You have to do

```
var conditions = {},
    type       = "stars",
    term       = "5";

conditions[type] = term;
App.Response.find(conditions);
```

---

If you find yourself using this pattern a lot, you could setup something like

```
var buildObject = function(key, value) {
  var base = {},
      base[key] = value;
  return base;
};

var type = "stars",
    term = "5";

App.Response.find(buildObject(type, term));

// or directly as
App.Response.find(buildObject("stars", "5"));
```

---

Lastly, let's make the `buildObject` helper a little more useful

```
// accepts [key, value] pairs
var buildObject = function() {
  var base = {};
  for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    base[arguments[i][0]] = arguments[i][1];
  };
  return base;
};
```

Now we can pass in multiple pairs

```
App.Response.find(buildObject(["stars", "5"], ["foo", "bar"]));

// equivalent to
App.Response.find({stars: "5", foo: "bar"});
```